# How to pass 3 parameters to the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

This my controller,which takes date:

```
public ActionResult ViewLevel(string datepicker)
        {
            @ViewBag.DatePicker = datepicker;
            return View();
        }
```

I have View:

```
@model Car

@{
    var datepicker = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.DatePicker);
}
<div class = "Conteiner"
@foreach (Car car in Model)
        {
<p data-carnumber="@car.Number"> @car.Number<p>
<button class="buyCar">Buy</button>
}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.Conteiner').on("click", ".buyCar", function () {
        var number = $(this).data("carnumber");
        window.location.href = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Form", "Buy", new {datepicker,number}))';
    });
</script>
```

datepicker I need to pass too. Why not see number in `new {datepicker,number}` .number is red

Comment: you can't pass a javascript variable into asp code...they run in different environments and at different times. That asp code is run on server long before the browser ever sees it

Comment: What values are you expecting to appear instead of `datepicker` and `number`? In your current code, these would be generated as the page is processed from the server, and wouldn't hold the details of the JavaScript variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason I hate to see Razor injected into Javascript. It confuses the whole client/server separation (and it does not allow the scripts to be in separate JS files where debugging JS will actually work in Visual Studio!).

You need to construct the parameter part of the URL at run-time on the client side, using the selected values:

e.g.

```
 var staticUrl = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Form", "Buy", new { datepicker=datepicker}))"
 $('.Conteiner').on("click", ".buyCar", function () {
      var number = $(this).prev().data("carnumber");
    window.location.href = staticUrl + "&number=" + number;
});
```

Here I inject *only* the main part of the action URL and leave the parameters to be added at click time.

Normally I inject only the site root URL into a global var with something like this in the layout file:

```
<script>
    window.siteRoot = @Url.Content("~/");
</script>
```

and use that URL in my JS/jQuery everywhere the site root is needed.

```
 $('.Conteiner').on("click", ".buyCar", function () {
      var number = $(this).prev().data("carnumber");
    window.location.href = siteRoot + "buy/form?datapicker=" + datepicker + "&number=" + number;
});
```

Comment: onclick nothing happens((((

Comment: And what have to done to debug it? :) Put an `alert()` in place of `window.location.href` and confirm the URL is valid.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: datepicker is not defined.    datepicker - its a date (string)

Comment: @{var datepicker = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.DatePicker);}

Comment: @andrey1567: datepicker was not in the original question, so I assumed you would update that yourself. Can you provide the full code in the question?

Comment: Updated to inject `datapicker` as the first parameter of the `staticUrl`

Comment: It contain date when the client buys the car.In Home page client change date when he want buy car .

Comment: According to your example layout, the span with the number is in the element before the `.buyCar` button. Can you confirm that is the case in the real page as `.prev()` may not be enough?

Comment: Wow! var number = $(this).data("carnumber") is Work.  very-very big Thanks

Comment: Oh no((( if I pass data-type    string, my parameter is undefined(( why?         <p data-color = "@car.Color"> @car.Color</p>

Comment: Sounds like a new problem. Perhaps time for a new question?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a syntax error:

Correct would be new {parametername1=value1, parametername2=value2}.

Seconds (as comments pointed out) you can't use a javascript variable (client/browser side) in an @Html Method (serverside).
One trick I used to solve this problem is to use placeholders in the @Html.Action like new {date="###THEDATE###", number="###THENUMBER###"} and with the corresponding string that @Html returns (and which is sent to the browser and comes to rest in a javascript variable) on client side the placeholder are replaced with javascript using the string replace function.

Comment: That is server-side. This solution requires client-side values by the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your problem is that you are trying to use a javascript variable in a razot Html helper parameter.

You cannot do this because razor syntax is executed on the server and javascript is executed client side.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432572/4871263) answer