# How passing AngularJS variables to Razor function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

it is possible to pass angularjs variable into razor function from Views?

By example, I need to do that things :

`@Html.Partial("_ViewName", new Models() { Url = {{ angularJSVariable }} })`

It is possible? If yes, how to do that? If no, what is the normal procedure to achieve that from an AngularJS context?

Thank you very much,

Karine

Comment: What i can understand from you question is that you are trying to retrieve a partial view using ajax. Right? If this is the case, you can create a angularjs service/factory to retrieve the view passing the angularjs variable in the url and get the html that you can inject into the DOM. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass anything from javascript to razor without going through the server.

Razor  executed in server side and  javascript is in client side...for more information check this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991161/pass-js-variable-or-inout-value-to-razor)